# OpenGL follow object smoothly

Tags: c++, opengl, camera

I have this little spaceship I want to follow and be smoothly about it. So I calculcate my mouse-coordinates and the offset from the last frame, add a **yaw** (x-coordinate) and a **pitch** (y-coordinate), then I do a little geometry et voilá I have my new front-vector for the followedObject.

Currently I follow my object like this:

```
void Camera::update()
{ 
    glm::vec3 objPosition = followedObject->GetPosition();
    this->position = objPosition;
    this->position.z += 15;
    this->camFront = followedObject->getFront();
    this->viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(position, position + camFront, camUp);
}
```

The z-Offset is used so the object is actually before the camera. Now this whole stuff is rather suboptimal. It worked great as long as I only moved the camera around, but now I really need a better solution.

I'd like to always center the followedObject on my screen and when I perform a curve or any direction change I want the camera to follow smoothly (like with a little transition)

Do you have any ideas how I could improve this?

Comment: Two things spring to mind here.  The first involves using a quaternion to interpolate (slerp) between your current camera eye vector and the desired "following" eye vector (which is from camera to look-at point).  The second is something I remember from an ancient Graphics Gems book concerning the calculation of reference frames along a curve.  Not sure if either concept is precisely what you want though. http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~blob/courses/305/notes/pdf/ref-frames.pdf

Comment: @Robinson Looks interesting, thanks! I am a beginner though and I need to polish things up a bit first, I guess. For now I'd like to make tiny steps and I'd love to have my object always in the center of the screen and the camera always behind (and a bit above) it. No success so far as every calculation adds other problems *sighs*